# How to update/set a new value, while iterating Hash Map object in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I need help on update the values while iterating Hash Map object.

Suppose , I have one Hash Map object like this ,

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("X", "D10023A");
hashMap.put("DATE", "5/1/2020");
hashMap.put("Y", "");
hashMap.put("Z", "");
hashMap.put("A", "");
```

I need to iterate over this Hash Map object, while iterating we need to check the condition i.e if Key=DATE and it's value = "5/1/2020", then need to update/set other key's i.e Y,Z,A values are, from empty("") strings to some integer values.

Please help me here.

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over the `HashMap` if you know what key to check and what keys to update?

Comment: Because I have more objects like this , need to iterate and DATE values can be differ so I need to check if DATE = 5/1/2020 then only I need to update other values as well.

Comment: This honestly looks like you are using a Map for something that it isn't really meant for. Are you sure you wouldn't be better of with a custom class that encapsules your properties X, Y, Z, A and Date in a single object?

Comment: In a `Map`, one can only store one value under a key. If one needs to store multiple values under one key, one should use `Map<K, List<V>>`. But then again... one would iterate over the `Listobtained by `map.get("DATE")`, not over the map itself. I second @OHGODSPIDERS's comment.

Comment: Because here problem is happening when I am doing iterate with entrySet() already I am in one index. My question is do we have any option to do update in next entries though we are in one index ?

Comment: It is  not required to store multiple values in one key, I need to replace the old values with new ones.

Comment: If you don't need to store multiple values in one key, then you don't have more objects like this (in the same `Map`, at least). I second (or rather, third) the general consensus that you're using a `Map`for something that needs something other than a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

`Map.Entry` has backward connection to the `Map` instance. I.e. when you modify an `Entry`, `Map` is modified as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("X", "D10023A");
    map.put("DATE", "5/1/2020");
    map.put("Y", "");
    map.put("Z", "");
    map.put("A", "");

    if ("5/1/2020".equals(map.get("DATE"))) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if ("DATE".equals(entry.getKey()))
                continue;
            if ("".equals(entry.getValue()))
                entry.setValue("666");
        }
    }
}
```